# Is there a way to delete similar words from array's elements?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to delete similar words from array's elements?

Initial array:

```
var arr = ["element first", "element second", "element third"];
```

Desired result:

```
var result = ["first", "second", "third"];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Do you know that "element" specifically is the part you want removed? Or are you asking if there's a generic way to remove "the shared string that all the items start with, whatever it is"?

Comment: The question is tremendously underspecified. Please define how you define »similar« elements: start with same string? or contain anywhere? And only if it affects all items or just any subset of them?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to do this "the shared string that all the items start with, whatever it is"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the first word in all strings.

```
var arr = ["element first", "element second", "element third"];

var output = []; 
for (var i =0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var items =  arr[i].split(" ");
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(items[0] + " ", "");
    output[i] = arr[i];
}

console.log(output);
```

Output is your desired array.

Answer (score 2):

You could find the common characters (at the same index) and filter the characters of the strings.

```js
var array = ["element first", "element second", "element third"],
    common = array
        .map(a => [...a])
        .reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v === b[i] ? v : null))
        .filter(Boolean),
    result = array.map(a => [...a].filter((v, i) => v !== common[i]).join(''));
    
console.log(result);
console.log(common);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Using ES6.

```js
const arr = ["element first", "element second", "element third"];

const replaced = arr.map(el => el.replace('element ',''));

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary of the words contained in the `arr` array and assign a index to each entry in the dictionary. This would like this:

```js
var wordList = ["element first", "element second", "element third"]
// this could be a object, but im going with a Map
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
var wordMap = new Map()

for(var i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
  var words = wordList[i].split(/\s/)
  // go trough every (possible) word
  for(var j = 0; j < words.length; j++) {
    var word = words[j]
    // check if the map already contains the word
    if(!wordMap.has(word)) {
      // the map doesn't contain the word, add it
      wordMap.set(word, [i])
    } else {
      // the map already contains the word, get the current indexes
      var override = wordMap.get(word)
      // add the current index to the list
      override.push(i)
      // update the map entry
      wordMap.set(word, override)
    }
  }
}

var mapEntries = wordMap.entries()
var iterator = mapEntries.next()
// go trough every map entry
while(!iterator.done) {
  var word = iterator.value[0]
  var indexes = iterator.value[1]
  // there must be atleast one index
  if(indexes.length !== 1) {
    // there are multiple indexes
    for(var k = 0; k < indexes.length; k++) {
      // remove the word and assign the new string to the position of the old string
      // the RegExp and the String.trim functions are used to remove unnecessary whitespace
      wordList[k] = wordList[k].replace(new RegExp(word + '\\s?'), '').trim()
    }
  }
  // get the next entry pair
  iterator = mapEntries.next()
}

console.log(wordList)
```

Answer (score 0):

- Reduce the array to its common prefix using a proper tail-recursive function to establish the subset of the current prefix that matches the start of the current string
- Map the array to a new array of strings that are a slice of characters past the prefix length.

```js
const arr = ["element first", "element second", "element third"],
  pre = arr.reduce((pfx, b) => toPrefix(pfx, b)),
  res = arr.map(a => a.slice(pre.length));

console.log("removed: %s\nresult: %s", JSON.stringify(pre), JSON.stringify(res));

function toPrefix(pfx, b, n = 0) {
  return b[n] && pfx[n] === b[n] ? toPrefix(pfx, b, n+1) : b.slice(0, n);
}
```